Update items in a recycler view in a regular interval
I am trying to develop an app in android that shows me the current value of some stocks. I do this using a RecyclerView with an Adapter that binds this RecyclerView to a list of stocks from the database. The current value however is not stored in the database, but rather polled from an API. I do this by having a background thread in the Adapter that updates the stocks in a regular interval. The stocks in turn have an event that notifies the ViewHolder associated with the stock when the value of a stock item has changed. This works, but is messy because I am now mixing a database model with ui properties. And my approch with a background thread in the Adapter is probably not the right one either. I know that there is a ViewModel pattern in Android. But this does not seem to fit my situation because I would need a view model for each item in the RecyclerView rather than just one ViewModel instance for the entire application.
The questions now are where do I deal with the background thread that updates the price of the stocks. Right now its inside the adapter, which is probably wrong. The other question is how do I separete the data model (stock) from UI related properties / logic?
@Entity
public class Stock {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int uid;

    // ...

    @ColumnInfo(name = "symbol")
    public String symbol;


    @Ignore // Regulary updated by the StockAdapter to show in the UI
    private double price;

    public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    };

    @Ignore // Required to notify the ViewHolder about the price change
    private final PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(java.beans.PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(java.beans.PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void setPrice(double price){
        double oldPrice = this.price;
        this.price = price;
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("price", oldPrice, price);
    }
}


Having a background thread in the Adapter for stock price updates isn't ideal, use the ViewModel pattern with LiveData to separate from your code structure.
